# [{"command":"settings","settings" error editing drupal view

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, view, drupal-7

I have a strange situation .
I have a view with blocks and page exposed and for a specific page, in my case is the main view page that exposes filtered forms for my content , when i want to add or edit a field i get :

`[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/tt\/","pathPrefix":""` .
I have tried to disable jquery update, I put on 1.5, nothing works, update the view, `dev` and stable version etc.

Using drupal 7.26 and view 7.x-3.7

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a jQuery AJAX issue to me. Try enabling Console on your browser's developer tools and watch for JavaScript errors, and try to make sense of them.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery was the issue for me that solved this. I rolled back to 1.5 and used no CDN and it worked finr